Simulating Objects moving SIMULTANEOUSLY at random direction
I'm working on a project where I simulate an ocean ecosystem with turtles, trash/plastics, and ships. They are pre-populated in the 2D grid, and they move randomly (ships tend to move more than stay idle, turtles are a bit more idle, and trash mostly stays idle in the grid).
They have the following relationships where:
std::map<std::pair<Ocean::Occupy, Ocean::Occupy>, Ocean::CollisionResult> collision_logics = {
            // Turtle encounters an empty space -> It can move.
            { {Ocean::Occupy::Turtle, Ocean::Occupy::Empty},   Ocean::CollisionResult::Move },
            // Turtle encounters trash -> It dies.
            { {Ocean::Occupy::Turtle, Ocean::Occupy::Trash},   Ocean::CollisionResult::Die },
            // Turtle encounters a ship -> Movement is blocked.
            { {Ocean::Occupy::Turtle, Ocean::Occupy::Ship},    Ocean::CollisionResult::Block },
            // Turtle encounters another turtle -> Movement is blocked.
            { {Ocean::Occupy::Turtle, Ocean::Occupy::Turtle},  Ocean::CollisionResult::Block },

            // Trash encounters an empty space -> It can move.
            { {Ocean::Occupy::Trash,  Ocean::Occupy::Empty},   Ocean::CollisionResult::Move },
            // Trash encounters a turtle -> Movement is blocked.
            { {Ocean::Occupy::Trash,  Ocean::Occupy::Turtle},  Ocean::CollisionResult::Move },
            // Trash encounters another trash -> Movement is blocked.
            { {Ocean::Occupy::Trash,  Ocean::Occupy::Trash},   Ocean::CollisionResult::Block },
            // Trash encounters a ship -> Movement is blocked.
            { {Ocean::Occupy::Trash,  Ocean::Occupy::Ship},    Ocean::CollisionResult::Die },

            // Ship encounters an empty space -> It can move.
            { {Ocean::Occupy::Ship,   Ocean::Occupy::Empty},   Ocean::CollisionResult::Move },
            // Ship encounters trash -> It survives and remains functional.
            { {Ocean::Occupy::Ship,   Ocean::Occupy::Trash},   Ocean::CollisionResult::Move },
            // Ship encounters another ship -> Movement is blocked.
            { {Ocean::Occupy::Ship,   Ocean::Occupy::Ship},    Ocean::CollisionResult::Block },
            // Ship encounters a turtle -> Movement is blocked.
            { {Ocean::Occupy::Ship,   Ocean::Occupy::Turtle},  Ocean::CollisionResult::Block}
        };

Basically, turtles die eating trash; ships delete trash, etc.
However, I somehow need to update the ocean so that i apply the movements of each object and possible collisions between objects at the same time.
For example, in this grid:
    0 1 2 3
  0   o x   
  1     | x 
  2 o |   x 
  3   o     

we have 3 turtles(o), 3 trash(x), and 2 ships (|).
If they move randomly or stay idle, I need to take into consideration when they collide at different locations.
For example, if a turtle at (0,1) moves to (1,1) but the trash at (0,2) tries to move to (1,1) as well, I need to simulate that so that (1,1) remains as trash cause the turtle died encountering trash.
Another example would be if a turtle at (2, 0) tries to move to (2, 1), but the ship stays idle, the turtle's movement should be blocked, and remain at (2,0).
There are other possible combinations, and right now i have following code where I make a temporary grid and write the movements while reading from the original grid one by one:
      void update_grid() {
            // intialize the grid_copy
            std::vector<int> temp_grid(num_cells, static_cast<int>(Occupy::Empty));
            
            // Iterate over this grid:
            // iterate over rows:
            for (int i = 0; i < num_rows; ++i) {
                // iterate over columns:
                for (int j = 0; j < num_cols; ++j) {
                    // retrieve cell state from the grid (again, grid that's not getting updated)
                    Occupy curr_obj = static_cast<Occupy>(this->get_cell(i, j));  
              // then apply random movement based on what the curr object is

And most of my movement-related methods return tuples of {i, j, obj, new_i, new_j, new_obj}...
What could be the best way to approach this? I am realizing that I somehow need to apply these movements and collision logic simultaneously.
Thank you so much, I am going crazy over this.

It's a bit hard to represent given arbitrary rule definitions. For example, you have the scenario where ships block turtles, turtles block ships, but ships eat trash and trash kills turtles. So, if a turtle, ship, and trash all try to move to the same empty square then the solution is ambiguous. Does the turtle block the ship from arriving and therefore die? Or does the ship block the turtle and clean up the trash? You're gonna need to define a more priority-based approach. That's still hard, because you could have a dependency loop spanning multiple cells. This sounds like a graph problem.

Yes, i just realized that there's a considerable complexity in this... i chose wrong final project...haha I don’t know what a graph problem is, (never took DSA course) but this is due in 12 hours...should i just make simplifying assumptions such as any colliding objects should disappear?

It might be easiest to simplify. Have three boolean grids: ships, turtles, trash. Decide that ships are faster than turtles are faster than trash. So ships move first. Calculate the new ship positions, and don't allow simultaneous exchange of positions (i.e. one ship cannot move into a cell that another ship or turtle is moving out of). Calculate a new grid of ships, blocked by other ships and turtles. Replace the ships grid with this and delete any trash at those positions. Do the same for turtles, and kill off unlucky turtles. Finally, move trash and either clean up or kill a turtle.

Is there something unclear about my suggestion? You will waste precious time by asking non-specific questions like "can I get your help".

sorry about that, why would it be boolean grid instead of actual ships?

and how would i turn those grid back into the actual grid of ints?

That was just how I thought of it logically. You can do it with your enum approach if you want. Just take your current layout, then make a new empty grid and do all your "moves" into that grid. i.e fill it with all new ship positions, then do the turtle logic to move those guys in (testing against new ship positions, not old ones), then move all your trash in (again, testing new turtle and ship positions) and kill some turtles. Honestly, I haven't spent more than a couple of minutes thinking about how I would solve the problem. This is an implementation detail which is really up to you.

@paddy's suggestion is a good one: define a hierarchy of movement. Move the ships, then the turtles, then the trash. You can possibly save some time by generating all the potential moves, sort them by destination and object type, and then process. So any ship going to grid square (10,12) is updated, then the turtles going there, then the trash. And then on to the next grid location that has updates.

It's a really cool question! Perhaps someone had the same question over there

Can we add a tag of low-level-design to this post?

@amangupta for sure!
